# preserving special characters in Bash getopts arguments

Tags: bash, shell, escaping, special-characters, preserve

I have a function in a Bash shell script library that uses getopts to accept arguments. I want to specify a Bash command in one of these arguments. The function then proceeds to use this stored command for one purpose or another (for example, producing a GNOME desktop launcher in an automated way with this stored command specified as the execution of the launcher). How could I preserve the special characters in the command in a user-friendly way (and, by that, I mean in a way that would not require the user to escape special characters in the command specified or do something otherwise unusually difficult)?

So, the beginning of the function could feature something such as the following:

```
OPTIND=1; while getopts ":i:o:" options; do
    case "${options}" in
        i)
            command_1="${OPTARG}"
            ;;
        o)
            fileName_1="${OPTARG}"
            ;;
        \?)
            echo "invalid option -"${OPTARG}""
            return
            ;;
        :)
            echo "option -"${OPTARG}" requires an argument"
            return
            ;;
    esac
```

The command to be given as an argument of the function could be something such as the following:

```
echo "hello" | festival --tts
```

Answer (score 0):

You can mix common argument parsing with getopts:

```
OPTIND=1
while :; do
    case "${!OPTIND}" in
    --tts)
        TTS=true
        (( ++OPTIND ))
        ;;
    --another-with-arg)
        (( ++OPTIND ))
        # Perhaps add a check as well if optarg is valid.
        ANOTHER=${!OPTIND}
        (( ++OPTIND ))
        ;;
    *)
        if getopts ":ai:o:" options; then
            case "${options}" in
            i)
                command_1="${OPTARG}"
                ;;
            o)
                fileName_1="${OPTARG}"
                ;;
            \?)
                echo "invalid option -"${OPTARG}""
                return
                ;;
            :)
                echo "option -"${OPTARG}" requires an argument"
                return
                ;;
            esac
        else
            return
        fi
        ;;
    esac
done
```

Although if I was at it, [I wouldn't use getopts at all](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18932745/445221).

Answer (score 0):

My interpretation is that you want the user to be able to write something like:

```
my_script -i echo "hello" | festival --tts
```

and have the entire sequence after the -i, including the pipe character, accepted as an argument.

Unfortunately, that's really not possible. There's no magic a called script can do because the entire command line has been parsed before the script is called.

Of course, the user could write:

```
my_script -i 'echo "hello" | festival --tts'
```

but that will require heroic efforts if the desired command line contains apostrophes.

The "usual" approach (used, for example, by the `find` utility's `-exec` option) is to accept command line arguments until a `;` is found. Of course, the `;` needs to be escaped, as do any pipes or other shell meta-characters.

One thing you could do is to provide a separate option, perhaps `-I`, which reads one line from `stdin` and uses that as the command. That would be handy for complicated command lines which were difficult to quote, although it's a bit awkward if the utility also wants to use `stdin` for some other purpose. With that in place, the user could type:

```
my_script -I file <<"EOF"
very_complicated_command 'with$x' "$all kinds of punctuation" 2> logfile | even_pipes
EOF
```